# Butterfly flapping wings animation SVG

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

I'm trying to animate butterfly wings, which should look like butterfly flapping wings. Can you help me achieve this?

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfoy6hbc/

```css
.butterfly {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

.left-wing {
  animation: left 1s linear infinite alternate;  
  transform-origin: right;
}

.right-wing {
  animation: right 1s linear infinite alternate;  
  transform-origin: left;
}

@keyframes left{
  to {transform:rotateY(20deg)}
}
@keyframes right{
  to {transform:rotateY(-20deg)}
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_2" class="butterfly" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 442.32 429.5">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
    <g>
      <g class="left-wing">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M42.56,2.5c-8.1,6.9-11.3,21.2-16.1,71-3.9,41.1-6.6,57.7-13.6,83-2.9,10.5-3.5,14.1-3.1,18.9,1.6,17.6,20.9,37.3,52.2,53.3,13.2,6.7,39.3,17,58,22.8,15.2,4.7,45.5,12.5,48.6,12.5,2.4,0,2.9-3.9,2.9-24.9,0-39.9-7-88.3-16.9-118.2-11.4-33.9-28.4-59-64.1-94.8C71.96,7.7,60.36,0,50.96,0c-4.3,0-6,.5-8.4,2.5Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M32.76,237.1c-8.9,2.6-22.4,26.1-28.7,49.9-6.4,24.2-5.2,44.6,3.4,56.3,15.6,21.2,52,13.3,107-23.2,12.3-8.1,27.6-20.9,37.6-31.2,8.2-8.5,16.5-19,15.8-20.1-.3-.4-2.1-.8-4.1-.8-5.3,0-23.5-4.8-56-14.9-46.7-14.5-66.1-18.6-75-16Z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="right-wing">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M405.16,119c-20.1,2.3-56.1,10.1-72.2,15.7-29.1,10.1-53,25.5-79.6,51.1-14.6,14-31.7,32.8-43.9,48.2-9.9,12.5-24.2,33.8-23.7,35.4.4,1.3,26.4,12,41.3,17,15.7,5.3,56,15.2,69.2,17,6.2.9,17.7,1.6,25.5,1.6,27.2,0,42.9-6.5,50.5-20.8,1.8-3.3,3.2-6.6,3.2-7.3,0-2.4,11.2-29.4,17.2-41.4,3.3-6.6,13.7-25.5,23.1-42,23.1-40.7,28.1-52.3,26.2-62.1-.9-4.8-5.9-9.9-11.1-11.3-6.1-1.5-17.1-2-25.7-1.1Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M184.86,285.1c1.7,29,12.1,63.5,29.2,96.9,7.8,15.3,14.8,25.5,23.3,34.1,10,9.9,16.8,13.4,26.6,13.4s15-2.8,24-11.9c16.2-16.5,28.5-49.1,28.5-75.6,0-9.6-1.4-14-5.2-17.2-4-3.4-19-11.2-31.8-16.6-18.3-7.8-84-31.7-92.9-33.9l-2.4-.6.7,11.4Z"/>
      </g>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M189.66,216.6c-1.2.8-2.2,2.5-2.2,3.8,0,1.2-1.2,3.8-2.6,5.7-4.6,6.2-6.3,10.5-7.4,19.5-2,15.2-3.7,20.9-10.8,35.1-10.1,20.3-11.2,23.9-11.1,38.1.1,17,.3,17.2,7.7,7.8,3.4-4.2,7.3-9.6,8.6-11.9,3.2-5.4,6.1-16.6,8.1-31.2,1.8-13.4,3.7-18.9,11.2-33.2,5-9.8,5.3-10.7,5.3-17.7,0-4.1.5-7.8,1-8.1,1.7-1,1.1-6.1-.8-7.8-2.3-2.1-4.1-2.1-7-.1Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the SVG code and CSS animations

Comment: Right now you're asking people to write code for you, instead of asking for help with solving a problem, so please [rephrase your question](/help/how-to-ask): show the [mcve] you already have, explain what you were hoping to do, and talk about _why_ you wrote the code you wrote, with an explanation of what you see it do instead of what you expected, and where you tried to already fix that, based on what line of thinking. There is nothing to "flap" in your question: CSS does nothing on its own. Your title talks about SVG, your tags talk about HTML, but neither are in your post yet.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I added a jsfiddle and SVG code with HTML and CSS. People has been editing the code and refactoring it just got deleted in that process.
Sorry I didn't mean anyone to write my code. I just need some help on some animation.

Comment: You don't need a jsfiddle, SO lets you write snippets in the post itself, so please move that code [into your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it you're not transforming relative to the coordinate of the butterfly body/the point where the wings meet the body. This becomes super obvious if you pick something like 120 degrees instead of 20, so: you probably want a different transform-origin property.

And to make "picking the right origin" *much* easier: export your butterfly without the rotations baked in, and then work on your animation transforms for that axis-aligned butterfly first. Then, once those work, all you need to do is rotate the *entire* butterfly by adding a `transform: rotate(...)` to the `.butterfly` class:

```css
.butterfly {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.left-wing {
  animation: left 1s linear infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: calc(50% - 10px) 0;
}

.right-wing {
  animation: right 1s linear infinite alternate;  
  transform-origin: calc(50% + 10px) 0;
}

@keyframes left {
  to {
    transform:rotateY(80deg)
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  to {
    transform:rotateY(-80deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="425" height="347" viewBox="0 0 425 347" class="butterfly">
   <g class="left-wing">
      <path d="M 3.25,6.76 C -4.76,25.69 4.27,46.37 6.75,65.56 14.46,100.95 22.40,136.62 22.61,173.00 c 3.94,24.18 30.50,33.68 51.07,39.65 42.38,9.42 86.46,8.82 129.48,4.56 -0.74,-23.72 -13.48,-45.91 -21.61,-68.07 C 162.29,104.79 135.37,61.45 93.11,35.75 70.03,22.05 46.59,6.50 19.95,1.04 14.11,0.51 6.82,1.60 3.25,6.76 z"/>
      <path d="m 65.65,233.12 c -12.55,15.35 -12.07,37.29 -12.06,56.28 1.39,21.08 6.32,48.74 28.95,56.75 24.19,4.94 44.32,-14.64 60.54,-29.88 25.67,-26.28 48.96,-56.42 60.65,-91.66 -10.50,-4.02 -34.04,2.36 -49.73,0.66 -28.26,1.12 -57.32,-1.40 -84.87,6.04 z"/>
   </g>
   <g class="right-wing">
      <path d="M 384.10,6.82 C 342.38,26.89 300.33,51.58 275.03,91.75 c -24.15,38.06 -43.48,79.81 -53.83,123.80 15.97,6.62 39.55,4.40 58.40,4.84 37.97,-2.15 79.42,-2.54 111.46,-25.75 18.11,-13.71 11.23,-38.03 14.84,-57.30 C 409.50,96.97 423.93,58.13 425.60,17.59 425.20,-7.03 398.35,0.14 384.10,6.82 Z" />
      <path d="m 225.14,232.32 c 16.51,39.80 44.53,74.74 78.20,101.41 14.53,10.95 36.75,20.29 52.19,5.71 19.62,-24.37 20.23,-59.03 13.70,-88.34 -1.21,-22.04 -24.69,-23.52 -41.67,-25.17 -35.43,-2.78 -71.03,-4.56 -106.57,-4.24 1.38,3.54 2.76,7.09 4.15,10.64 z" />
   </g>
   <path d="m 208.77,165.63 c -6.38,17.39 -1.35,35.52 -0.65,53.52 -1.69,19.82 -8.16,40.50 1.20,59.52 6.04,19.57 13.75,-15.67 13.20,-23.24 -0.60,-19.43 -7.44,-38.78 -2.02,-58.17 1.15,-6.41 1.76,-42.76 -11.73,-31.62 z" />
</svg>
```

And if you're going to put this on the web: optimize your SVG so it doesn't contain application-specific properties like layer ids, data attributes, `<defs>` that don't actually do anything, numbers with more than 2 digits after the decimal points, etc. No point in keeping *any* of that, it just makes your SVG needlessly big.

Answer (score 0):

There are no correct answer to your questions, but here is some advice

First you need to set your pivot point correctly, you have `transform-origin:left and right`, but as the svg fot the wings expand left AND right, i would advise puting a `transform-origin:center`, or in your specific case somewhere along `transform-origin:40% 65%`

Then amplify the movement of your wings and you will discover that it folds well along the X axis, but you will need a bit of folding along the other axis since you butterfly is not perfectly vertical.

Two solutions here : play with `rotateY`, or start with a vertical svg and when it's looking all good, rotate the whole `Layer 1`

Comment: I tried playing with rotateY and adjusting the transform-origin, but I was still not able to achieve the flapping correctly.